# Serilog - Logging in multiple languages

Tags: logging, internationalization, serilog

I have a situation where we write manufacturing software that is used in both the U.S. and in China. We'd like to be able to have this software create logs that are in both English and another language because this helps local technicians debug issues in their native language. Having the logs also in English helps us (in the U.S.) provide additional support when needed.

My question is with a logging package like Serilog, is there an established pattern for handling something like this?

I am considering two approaches thus far:

1. Have a single log sink that accepts dictionaries of localized
   strings (e.g. a set of resx files), and uses keys as the messages
   when logs are written.
2. Have multiple sinks (or multiple instances of a generic "resx sink") where each one is configured with a translated resx file that logs messages using keys (like option 1).

From the code of the sinks I feel like either of these approaches could work, but I'm wondering if there's something already out there to handle a case like this.